# Updating 2 tables from 1 html form using 2 mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update 2 tables on my database using 1 form. There are a couple of things that happen before the queries execute:

1. search the customers table using their phoneNum to see if they exist
2. If there is a match it populates the booking form with the name, address, phoneNum from the customer table. If there is no match the form fields stay empty.
3. Hit submit and the values in the booking form are posted to addbooking.php
4. The first query in addbooking.php either INSERTS a new customer (if none matched in the            previous search) or UPDATES the existing record (if there was a match)
5. The second query should add a record to the job table using the same values.
6. The first query works correctly doing an INSERT or an UPDATE
7. The second query works if the customer exists and will not work if the customer has to be created.

The issue is with the cutomerId that is passed from the form. If the cutomerId is passed from the form (meaning they exist) the second query works. If they don't exist then nothing is passed but the first query creates a new customer hence generating a new customerId.

So my question is how do I get the customerId from the first query and use it in the second? I have all the code but hopefully I have explained the problem enough that the queries themselves will be enough. Many thanks!

```
    $query1 =   "INSERT INTO customer (customerId, name, address, phoneNum)" . 
            "VALUES ( '$customerId','$name', '$address', '$phoneNum')" .
            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='$name', address='$address', phoneNum='$phoneNum'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1)
or die('Error adding new customer.');
//edit as per Jessica
$customerId = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO job (jobType, carType, customerId, phoneNum, name, address, destAdd, bookingDate, BookingTime)" . 
            "VALUES ('$jobType', '$carType', '$customerId', '$phoneNum', '$name', '$address', '$destAdd', '$bookingDate', '$bookingTime')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
or die('Error adding booking.');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysqli_insert_id`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id)

```
$customerId = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);
```

PS: Why on earth are you inserting raw data in your queries instead of using parameters?

Comment: He is using mysqli, that's why it's so silly to not be using parameters.

Comment: Oops. Mistake there. Thought he was using MySQL. Haha. +1 anyways.

Comment: @Jessica, thanks for your help that's working now. I'm new to MySQL so the method I've used above is the one I've found in most books. I'm open to changing the code if there is a better way.. I did change some of it to use MySQLi as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: So, the next step is to use Prepared Statements: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Jessica, I tested the original problem and as stated above your code fixed it but now the second query will not run if the customer already exists meaning it doesn't work in reverse. Is this because your line changes the customerID so there is no longer a valid value being passed accross? Is there any way to fix this now for both or did I use your code incorrectly? Many thanks, Eoin.

Comment: The code you showed doesn't show anything having to do with a check to see if the customer already exists.

Comment: Its done in a previous page.. I mentioned it in point 1 and 2 in the description. Its just a text field in a form used to compare what the user types to the phoneNum field in the customer table. If there is a match it populates the customerId(hidden), name, address and phoneNum fields in the booking form. These values are then used in the queries listed above. Does that make sense?